# How much time it will take to build CiviCRM from scratch by single person?

Tags: evaluating-civicrm, civicrm-home

This question is just to have an idea of the effort that has gone into building CiviCRM. How much time will it take to build CiviCRM from scratch by a single person? including testing and fixing the bugs.

Answer (score 6):

All of it? Probably 10 years.

(that's a serious answer - I know, as a member of the core team, I built a lot of it myself)

Answer (score 2):

Building the entire thing? My guess is at this point it's tens of thousands of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're attempting to create an ever-evolving target, I'd say that you'd never be able to do it.